# Какая папка в Django является корневой?

Tags: django, debian, vps

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какая папка в Django является корневой? Нужно туда файлик закинуть. Используется Debian на VPS.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В Django не бывает папок, и корневой тоже нет.

Comment: Прикольно. И как быть?

Comment: @ArgumentSite Поверх `Django` у Вас есть сервер? (`Nginx`, например). Вот в нём и пропишите `location` к этому файлу.

Comment: Там таких файликов может быть не один десяток. Для каждого запаришься прописывать.

Comment: @ArgumentSite Тогда пропишите `root` к папке с этими файлами.

Comment: root в комбинации с try_files, да

Comment: А можно, пожалуйста, поподробней пример, а то только начал во всем этом разбираться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно раздавать эти файлы с помощью `Nginx`.

Например, так:

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        root /path/to/files;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
    ...
}
```

После подтверждения сайта Вам нужно будет удалить этот `location` или сделать проксирование на другой, добавив параметр к [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files):

```
location / {
    root /path/to/files;
    try_files $uri @django;
}

location @django {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Тогда к Django не будет доступа, это не круто скорее всего

Comment: @andreymal Можно проксировать. Добавил пример.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Папка, как корневая заработала. Только теперь главная страница выдает Server Error (500)

Comment: @ArgumentSite Вы второй вариант используете?

Comment: @nomnoms12 Да, второй

Comment: @ArgumentSite Покажите, пожалуйста, блок `location @django` и ошибку, которая возникает на сервере.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Так же надо было?

location / {
    root /path/to/file;
    try_files $uri @ django;
    }

    location @ django {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

Comment: @ArgumentSite У Вас пробел перед знаком `@`? Попробуйте его убрать

Comment: @nomnoms12 Server Error (500)

Comment: @nomnoms12 Пробел это только здесь, иначе stackoverflow думает, что я отвечаю пользователю django

Comment: @ArgumentSite Нужно определить, где проблема. Для начала проверьте конфигурацию `Nginx`: `nginx -t`. Потом можно проверить его логи: `var/log/nginx/error.log`. Если ошибка не в нём, то смотрите логи Вашего `WSGI`.

Comment: Вроде все заработало нормально. Это я, видимо, в шаблоне base.html допустил ошибку и из-за этого ругалось

Comment: @ArgumentSite Рад помочь :)